# About Haar Like Feature Equation

Tags: opencv, haar-wavelet

I want to know the Haar-Like Feature equation. That can prove any Edge Feature, Line Feature and Center-Surround Feature.

Best Thank
Chairat(Thailand)

Comment: Please, improve your question and try to be specific about what you need.

Answer (score 0):

There is no equation of such, they are filters that are calculated by taking weighted sums of integrated areas of the images. There is a brief description of this in the OpenCV [Cascade Classification](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html#CascadeClassifier) documentation. The best thing to do is read the Viola and Jones paper:

[Paul Viola and Michael J. Jones. Rapid Object Detection using a Boosted Cascade of Simple Features. IEEE CVPR, 2001.](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~roland/Courses/ENGN8530_CVIU/viola_jones_CVPR2001_AdaBoost_Cascade.pdf)